# Haskell obscure file path operations (simplify away the dots)

Tags: haskell, filepath

I have a dynamically constructed file path in haskell that ends up something like this:

```
/abc/def/../ghi/./jkl
```

and I'd like to reduce it to the more readable

```
/abc/ghi/jkl
```

For printing. Is there a library function to do this in haskell? I've looked all over and can't find one. It's not too hard to write, but it's a bit messy because you have to "look ahead" for ".."s, and I'd rather use a baked-in function if I can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beware that this is not simply a string processing question when links are involved:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar
$ ln -s foo/bar baz
$ echo gotcha! >foo/quux
$ cat quux
cat: quux: No such file or directory
$ cat baz/../quux
gotcha!
```

So you need to do IO.

The nearest I can find to what you want is [`canonicalizePath`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v:canonicalizePath) from `System.Directory`. It returns a path starting from the root directory, so you may want to use it in conjunction with [`makeRelative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/1.1.0.4/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:makeRelative), also from `System.Directory`. But it does run in `IO`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [System.FilePath.Posix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html).  The [normalise](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v%3anormalise) function does *almost* what you want:

```
> normalise "/abc/def/../ghi/./jkl"
"/abc/def/../ghi/jkl"
```

You could use [`splitDirectories`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/filepath/latest/doc/html/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v%3asplitDirectories) to split the file name and simplify processing.

Beware of edge cases such as:

```
/../foo        -- Equal to /foo, at least on my system
../parent/foo  -- Requires a system call to eliminate the possibly-redundant ..
```